# How can I save a JDeveloper 11g application to new folder?

Tags: jdeveloper

I want to save a Jdeveloper application which includes 2 projects to a new folder, leaving out the files I have excluded from the project contents.

Is there a way to do it from JDeveloper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to copy & paste.

Save all your data and exit JDev.  It's not mandatory, but it's always a good idea with JDev.

Copy your tree to a new location and open it up in JDev.  Everything should be in the right place.  This will copy over the files you want to exclude, but you could write an ant script to delete them or just ignore them.